# What does it mean when the tag value returned in an opentsdb query response is "node"?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, opentsdb

This is relevant to Opentsdb 2.3.1 writing to Google Cloud BigTable (the Opentsdb config can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/quekshuy/6dd592db4ca69870840b4e795925c894)).

I'm writing to OpenTSDB time series like this (via the HTTP API -- `api/put`) like so:

```
{
   "metric": "w.builder.9",
   "timestamp": 1535504606,
   "value": 1,
   "tags": {
      "tid": "1",
      "wid": "21",
      "vid": "17"
   }   
}
```

where `wid` and `vid` are just integers (surrounded by quotes).

Now when I run a simple query with no aggregation, i.e.

```
{
  "start": "1h-ago",
  "queries": [
    {
      "metric": "w.builder.9",
      "aggregator": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

**QUERY RESPONSE**

```
[
    {
        "metric": "w.builder.9",
        "tags": {
            "wid": "node",
            "tid": "1",
            "vid": "node"
        },
        "aggregateTags": [],
        "dps": {
            "1535503901": 1,
            "1535503951": 1,
            "1535504407": 1,
            "1535504576": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "metric": "w.builder.9",
        "tags": {
            "wid": "node",
            "tid": "1",
            "vid": "node"
        },
        "aggregateTags": [],
        "dps": {
            "1535503881": 1,
            "1535503960": 1,
            "1535503982": 1,
            "1535504389": 1,
            "1535504402": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Why are tag values for `wid` and `vid` = `"node"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 reasons this was happening:

1. The data is stored in Bigtable instead of HBase.
2. The config had salting enabled.

I removed the following line from our config and the issue went away:

```
tsd.storage.salt.width = 1
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug with OpenTSDB + Bigtable - is that your understanding as well? It seems like salting should work in this configuration.